# React-Laravel(7.2) Component not showing in blade.php

Tags: javascript, php, html, reactjs, laravel-7

I am trying to use a react component in my my PHP laravel project but the component does not show
It keeps showing a blank area but so I tried inserting an h1 tag in the div block of the id='footercomp' but nothing also works in it.
I run

```
composer laravel/ui react
npm install
npm run dev
php artisan ui react
```

HTML

```
<footer class="footer-section">
  <div id='footercomp'>

  </div>
</footer>
<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

require('./components/FooterComp')
```

FooterComp

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

export default class FooterComp{
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6 order-1 order-md-2">
                        <div className="footer-social-links">
                            <a href=""><i className="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
                            <a href=""><i className="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                            <a href=""><i className="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                            <a href=""><i className="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
                            <a href=""><i className="fa fa-behance"></i></a>
                            <div className="col-md-6 order-2 order-md-1">
                                <div className="copyright">
                                    Copyright &copy;
                                    <script type="fdd38016b2c0a37d3fefa1a8-text/javascript">
                                        document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
                                    </script>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
} 

export default FooterComp

if (document.getElementById('footercomp')){
    ReactDOM.render(<FooterComp />,document.getElementById('footercomp'));
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to export your component twice. Doing it once just before the rendering is enough. Not sure if that's causing your issue though. Any luck with it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add app.js in your layout file ?

I was having same issue and found out that didn't added app.js